# Best way to emulate git submodules in svn

Tags: svn

I really like the submodule functionality of git, and I have been using it a lot since I switched from svn to git as my personal "preferred tool".

The problem however is that you are not always free to chose the tool you prefer, and now I'm stuck with using svn for a project. I miss the submodule functionality. :(

Is there a way to do something similar in svn? Even if it isn't, is there something like a best practice of how something similar can be emulated, would it be possible to have a svn repo inside another svn repo and update it by a script somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at svn:externals?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html

I usually see people moving from SVN to Git and looking for an alternative to how they used to use svn:externals.  Git Submodules is the main equivalent though it lacked some of the features of SVN.  I believe newer Git versions are even more similar though there are still obviously differences.

http://alexking.org/blog/2012/03/05/git-submodules-vs-svn-externals

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need. Thanks! I found a very to-the-point tutorial here: http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/q8/Short-tutorial-on-svn-propset-for-svnexternals-p.html